# Função in_array() do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, select

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que pega os ID's de categorias que estão armazenados no banco de dados, separados por `,`, estou utilizando `explode`, transformando-as em um `array`e logo em seguida estou utilizando a função `array_rand()` para sortear apenas um valor deste array. Tudo funcionando perfeitamente, porém necessito agora pegar outros registros que contenham a mesma categoria desta sorteada. Caso o valor retorne `false`(vazio), preciso sortear novamente até que encontre um registro com esta categoria, para que não ocorra de a barra lateral ficar sem registros sendo exibidos.

### Visualizando um anúncio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observe por exemplo neste anúncio as categorias são Alimentacao e Atendente

Desejo em minha barra lateral buscar outros anúncios que sejam da mesma categoria e com `ORDER BY rand()`, vejam um exemplo da barra lateral.

- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As categorias estão armazenadas no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
anuc_cat_id = 1,7,2,9  | ID's das categorias

anuc_anu_id = 2  | Indica a qual anúncio corresponde
```

## Separação das categorias e sorteio

```
$categoriasAnuncioAtual = explode(',', $rowCategoriasAnuncioAtual->anuc_cat_id);
$categoriaRandomAtual = $categoriasAnuncioAtual[array_rand($categoriasAnuncioAtual)];
```

## Consulta no banco de dados e verificação

```
$selParecidos = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM anuncios a
                                        INNER JOIN anuncios_categorias ac ON ac.anuc_anu_id = a.anu_id
                                        INNER JOIN anuncios_fotos af ON af.anuf_anu_id = a.anu_id AND af.anuf_posicao = ?
                                        INNER JOIN usuarios u ON a.anu_usu_id = u.usu_id
                                        WHERE a.anu_url <> ? AND a.anu_status = ? AND a.anu_status_adm = ?
                                        GROUP BY anu_id
                                        ORDER BY rand()');
$selParecidos->execute(array(0, $rowId->anu_url, 1, 1)); 
$rowParecidos = $selParecidos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

$arraycategoriasbanco = explode(',', $rowParecidos->anuc_cat_id);

//busca pelo array random dentro da variavel de categorias do anuncio
if(in_array($categoriaRandomAtual, $arraycategoriasbanco)){
    echo "existe"; 
}
```

Nas últimas linhas do código onde se segue `if(in_array())` necessito que caso não exista ele faça um novo `SELECT` até encontrar um registro que corresponda a este `if()`.
**Como posso proceder?**

> Não tenho erros no SELECT ou demais, apenas necessito uma maneira de reexecutar o select caso `if(in_array())` seja vazio. Pensei em fazer uma `function()` mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Você tem certeza que quer ficar repetindo o `SELECT`? Não sei se entendi o problema mas mudar a ordem não vai fazer mudar o resultado do `in_array()`.

Comment: No caso meu sistema mostra anúncios, quando estou na página de um determinado anúncio tenho detalhes sobre ele, porém quero exibir na barra lateral anúncios semelhantes da mesma categoria daquele que estou visualizando. Não sei se repetir o select é uma boa forma, porém preciso de uma maneira que quando o valor no caso do campo `anuc_cat_id` não corresponda aos do array ele faça uma nova consulta ou algo do tipo para buscar anuncios que correspondam a estes parâmetros.

Comment: Você pode colocar o `SELECT` numa variável e no if chamar novamente o `$conn->prepare($variavel)`.

Comment: Gostei da lógica, cheguei bem próximo de um resultado semelhante, parece-me que o Bruno Calza que respondeu abaixo apresentou algo parecido. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que um `do-while` resolva:

```
$categoriasAnuncioAtual = explode(',', $rowCategoriasAnuncioAtual->anuc_cat_id);

do{
    $categoriaRandomAtual = $categoriasAnuncioAtual[array_rand($categoriasAnuncioAtual)];
    $selParecidos = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM anuncios a
                                            INNER JOIN anuncios_categorias ac ON ac.anuc_anu_id = a.anu_id
                                            INNER JOIN anuncios_fotos af ON af.anuf_anu_id = a.anu_id AND af.anuf_posicao = ?
                                            INNER JOIN usuarios u ON a.anu_usu_id = u.usu_id
                                            WHERE a.anu_url <> ? AND a.anu_status = ? AND a.anu_status_adm = ? AND ac.anuc_cat_id
                                            GROUP BY anu_id
                                            ORDER BY rand()');
    $selParecidos->execute(array(0, $rowId->anu_url, 1, 1)); 
    $rowParecidos = $selParecidos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

    $arraycategoriasbanco = explode(',', $rowParecidos->anuc_cat_id);

}while(!in_array($categoriaRandomAtual, $arraycategoriasbanco));
```

O código acima **corre riscos de entrar em loop infinito**.

Para evitar isso, eu removeria a categoria sorteada da `$categoriasAnuncioAtual` e adicionaria a condição `!empty($categoriasAnuncioAtual)` dentro da condição do `while`.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Somente uma dúvida, qual a função exata que o `do` tem ao complementar um `while`, não conhecia esta função.

Comment: Teria uma maneira de eu evitar o risco de um loop infinito? Ou desta maneira seria sem utilizar o while e tentar outra lógica?

Comment: são iguais exceto pelo momento em que executam a condição de saída do loop. o do-while executa no fim e o while no começo

Comment: @TiagoBoeing já complementei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado, exatamente isto que eu necessitava!

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer com Uma função que execute o `SELECT` e depois um `while` enquanto a condição não for satisfeita.

```
function getCategoriasBanco($conn, $rowId)
{
    $selParecidos = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM anuncios a
                                        INNER JOIN anuncios_categorias ac ON ac.anuc_anu_id = a.anu_id
                                        INNER JOIN anuncios_fotos af ON af.anuf_anu_id = a.anu_id AND af.anuf_posicao = ?
                                        INNER JOIN usuarios u ON a.anu_usu_id = u.usu_id
                                        WHERE a.anu_url <> ? AND a.anu_status = ? AND a.anu_status_adm = ? AND ac.anuc_cat_id
                                        GROUP BY anu_id
                                        ORDER BY rand()');
    $selParecidos->execute(array(0, $rowId->anu_url, 1, 1)); 
    $rowParecidos = $selParecidos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

    $arraycategoriasbanco = explode(',', $rowParecidos->anuc_cat_id);

    return $arraycategoriasbanco;
}

$arraycategoriasbanco = getCategoriasBanco($conn, $rowId);
//busca pelo array random dentro da variavel de categorias do anuncio
while(!in_array($categoriaRandomAtual, $arraycategoriasbanco))
{
    $arraycategoriasbanco = getCategoriasBanco($conn, $rowId); 
}
```

Comment: Isto faz o que parece que ele está pedindo mas duvido que resolva o problema de fato. Mas sei lá, a pergunta não indica claramente o intuito. XY.

Comment: Adicionei umas capturas de tela e mais alguns detalhes para tentar exclarecer.

Comment: @bigown foquei-me só em responder ao pedido.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Consegui solucionar pela questão do while, verificando se satisfaz as condições e reexecutando caso negativo.